# RuntimeError: index 99 is out of bounds for dimension 0 with size 99

Tags: bipartite, pytorch-geometric, graph-neural-network

I'm working on PyTorch geometric I have a `RuntimeError: index 99 is out of bounds for dimension 0 with size 99` issue. My dataset is a bipartite graph.

- Source shape is 32,3 [nodes,feature]
- target size is 100,3 [nodes,feature]
- edge_index is 2,745 [2, index]

Answer (score 0):

The error message

> RuntimeError: index 99 is out of bounds for dimension 0 with size 99

says you tried to access index 99 of the dimension 0 (maybe of target, which you say to be 100,3) when it only has a size of 99, so the only indexes you could have accessed would be 0-98.

It could be that  in your dataset your __ len __ is just 1 value greater than your actual data, or if you are sure about the dimentions could be that you skip one sample in your dataset which then is not found.

Comment: I try with torch.randn 32,3. It will not return any error. It will show error when i use own data.  My data shape 32 i can't change. What i have to do?

Comment: The index you're using is wrong, try to print it to find why it becomes 99. Moreover, the object size in the error is 99, are you sure of the shape of your data? If it works with torch.randn 32,3 , it may be because of your own dataset len implementation(or on how you get the shape that you pass as the index on Source)

Comment: I fix that error but the accuracy is very low. I have a doubt what will be y_label in bipartite graph. I want to predict the link.

Answer (score 0):

I found that this issue popped up due to "add_self_loops" in the CONV layer being set to true. Try setting it to false and see if that works.